# LAN->LAN IP translation for Buffalo router?

Tags: tortoisesvn, ip-address, router, artifacts

Here's my scenario:

I've got a VisualSVN server on my main dev box @ home. I'm also using a Visual Studio 2010, TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN client (for source control), and Versioned 'Artifacts' (for bug tracking).

I've got my Buffalo AirStation WHR-HP-G300N router properly configured so my business partner can connect to the SVN server. I have port forwarding enabled for the internet-side IP address (like http://99.888.77.66:443) which gets forwarded to an internal IP (like 192.168.11.6). This part is working great.

The problem I'm having is with the integration piece between TortoiseSVN and my bug tracking system. I need to provide a **bugtraq:url** property, but I haven't been able to get relative paths to work.  So I'm forced to use an absolute URL. On my end, I need to use the *name* of my server (for example: bugtraq:url = https://my-server/svn/bla..), but this doesn't work for my partner.  He needs to specify the IP address (for example: bugtraq:url = https://999.888.77.66:443/svn/bla...)

Is there a way to configure my router such that the IP address for this parameter gets re-routed/re-mapped to "https://my-server" if the request originates from the LAN itself?  My router's software supports LAN->Internet and Internet->LAN, but I don't see LAN->LAN.

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on serverfault.com.

Comment: Didn't know about ServerFault.com till your post above.  Looks like that's probably a good place to get some help.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, not even sure you can do that on a real router. Have you tried editing the host file? that would probably work.

Comment: I just tried something off-the-wall, but it didn't work, either. I tried to add my local copy of the TortoiseSVN folder (that gets modified when I change the bugtraq:url) to a changelist in SVN called "DoNotCommit". If figured this way I could keep a set of local change to this file and then never check them in. Unfortunately, seems like there's a but with TortoiseSVN if you do this. Changelists don't like working with folders, only files. If you create a changelist and drag a folder into it, it's automagically removed from the changelist the next time you view the changelist.

Comment: (Cont'd.) 
So I'm back to either: A) figuring out how to get relative paths working for the URL property (but I've tried everything I can think of already); or B) figuring out how to map an IP address navigation originating from my LAN to another IP added or a named URL.

Comment: Which "Host File" are you talking about? For the router or for my SVN repository?

Comment: The hosts file for the computer that needs the translation. Put an entry in like 99.888.77.66 my-server/svn/bla, this is basically the equivalent of a local DNS server.

Comment: I've been messing around with the Windows 7 HOST file, but that thing sure is finicky. I'm not able to reliably add an entry and then test it without having intermittent URL resolution failures in the browser.  **Seems** like this should work, but I haven't uncovered the magic syntax yet.

Comment: Editing the HOSTS file worked, but I had to get my partner to edit *his* HOSTS to make this work.

On my end, I changed the **bugtraq:url** property to "https://my-server/svn/bla" and checked in this change.  My partner synched to this change, then added the following line to his HOSTS file:

99.888.77.66   my-server

Works great!